# how to find the distinct with twist

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table A
SSN - PK
first_name 
Last_name

Table B 
SSN
Address (email)
Primary_email
```

I have a list of people who have several different email ID and have their assigned Primary email id as X.

```
e.g ryan C might have 2 diff email id     
ryan@gmail.com,    
ryan.p@verizon.com ( marked as primary email)
```

on the other hand i have several other people who have 2 or 3 email id with no primary email_Id assigned yet.

and every time the new email is recorded the sequence number is assigned based on the date 0 or 1 or 2. so i am trying to find the list of people who has email Id in table B not are not assigned as a primary ID yet.

this is what i have tried :

```
    select first_name, last_name    
    from table A     
     join table b    
    On a.ssn = b.ssn    
    and b.primary_email <> 'X'
```

I am very new to this, my apologies for any mistakes i might have made.

Comment: Please tell me you are not really using SSN as the primary key for your tables? This is sensitive information that should be encrypted at all times. As to your actual question, I have no idea what you are asking. Are you trying to find any SSN that does not have at least 1 primary email? What about having more than 1 primary email? Do you have a way to prevent that?

Comment: And you really should decide which DBMS you are using. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: You should consider changing Primary_Email to a non-nullable BIT field.  If a field can hold more than two values eventually it will.  This leads to missed records (where primary didn't equal X but something else instead).

Comment: sean its SQL server. my appologies.

Comment: Apart from the potential privacy concerns, SSNs are not necessarily unique.

Comment: Sorry, but LOL at the SSN comments.  Although I've seen most places come around to realize they aren't unique (and can change or be wrong!) so aren't good PKs, it's pretty common to have them in the DB as plaintext  with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL solution:

Please try the following solution using sub-query. Let me know if it works or not. I have no data to verify that.

```
SELECT 
    First_name, Last_name
FROM A
WHERE 
    A.ssn IN (  SELECT 
                    B.ssn
                FROM B
                GROUP BY B.ssn
                HAVING SUM(Primary_email = 'X') = 0);
```

Comment: With a small change with would work for SQL Server too.  The HAVING clause would read *COUNT(CASE WHEN Primary_Email = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) = 0*.  Of course you could also run the subquery on its own, if you only need the SSN.

Answer (score -1):

From what you are saying, you can just change the and to a where.  It isn't that you want multiple join conditions, but to limit the circumstances under which the join occurs.

```
select first_name, last_name    
from table A     
 join table b    
On a.ssn = b.ssn    
WHERE b.primary_email <> 'X'
```

Also, if values are not set, you might have to check for NULLs.

```
select first_name, last_name    
from table A     
 join table b    
On a.ssn = b.ssn    
WHERE b.primary_email IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi robert, but i am trying to get list of people whose primary_email has always been null. e.g i might have couple emails where one of my email might have been flagged as X, but i am looking for those population who never had their email flagged.

Comment: I did follow several steps where i did run the query to find the number of people who has Primary Email as X, and ran the next query find number of people who doesn't have X from the previous list, than ran the update query and i got what i was looking for. thank you all for your feed back.

Answer (score -1):

There are several different ways you can solve this problem.  They all follow the same basic pattern, which is to remove all the users with a primary email form the full list.

**Example Data**

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        Id          INT,
        Email       VARCHAR(255),
        IsPrimary   BIT
    )
;

/* Populate table with sample data.
 * Id 1 has a primary email address.
 * Id 2 does not.
 */
INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        Id,
        Email,
        IsPrimary
    )
VALUES
    (1, 'x@abc.com', 1),        -- Primary email address (ID 1).
    (1, 'x@def.com', 0),
    (1, 'x@ghi.com', 0),
    (2, 'y@abc.com', 0),
    (2, 'y@def.com', 0),
    (2, 'y@ghi.com', 0)
;
```

**NOT IN**

```
-- Using NOT IN.
SELECT
    s.Id
FROM
    @Sample AS s
WHERE
    Id NOT IN
        (
            -- Return all ids with a primary email.
            SELECT 
                Id
            FROM
                @Sample
            WHERE
                IsPrimary = 1
            GROUP BY
                Id
        ) 
GROUP BY
    s.Id
;
```

**EXCEPT**

```
    -- Full list.
    SELECT
        Id
    FROM
        @Sample
    GROUP BY
        Id

EXCEPT

    -- Exclude those with a primary.
    SELECT
        Id
    FROM
        @Sample
    WHERE
        IsPrimary = 1
    GROUP BY
        Id
```

For a more detailed explaination, and a couple of further methods, see this [blog post](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2015/12/31/the-missing-data-problem/).